# AppHarbor Unit Tests fails from missing file

Tags: appharbor

I'm using AWS S3 to store documents on my AppHarbor App and I've written a handful of unit tests to insure that my AWS connection is stable for every deployment. I've committed a sample image into the repository to test uploads but the image doesn't seem to transfer into the AppHarbor local repository. I'm getting this exception off all of my AWS S# unit tests:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
>   'D:\Core.Tests\data\upload_test.png'.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Is this expected AppHarbor or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably not being copied to the build output directory. Make sure that the file is checked into git and that it is referenced from your project with `Build Action` set to `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are several ways to do this correctly but I found a solution to my own problem by using the DeploymentItem Attribute like so:

> [TestClass]
>
> [DeploymentItem("data", "data")]
>
> public class ExternalTests
>
> {

instead of trying to reference the path of the folder with an absolute path like so:

> //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\..\..\..\Core.Tests\data\";

Cheers.